# Can a 2N7000 transistor withstand 4.7-5 V gate voltage?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, maximum-ratings

[Here is the datasheet of the 2N7000 transistor](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/2n7000-n-channel-enhancement-mode-vertical-dmos-fet-data-sheet-20005695a.pdf). I need to use it in a circuit where an Arduino will provide the gate terminal with 4.7-5 V and the transistor needs to withstand 200 mA current.

It seems the transistor will withstand the current, but can it tolerate the gate voltage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the datasheet says +/-30V between gate and source, absolute maximum. 4V to 5V is perfectly fine. As is +/-10V.

However it's a bit *low* to be guaranteed to switch 200mA. The part is specified with 4.5V at only 75mA. You should use guaranteed characteristics, not 'typical'.

Unless you need low gate charge for some reason, it would probably be better to use a higher performance logic-level MOSFET (most are SMT in packages like SOT23), such as the [AO3400](https://aosmd.com/sites/default/files/res/datasheets/AO3400.pdf), which has an on resistance of only 0.033Ω maximum with 4.5V in and switching 5A vs. 5.3Ω at 75mA. At 200mA the voltage drop of a 2N7000 could be greater than 1V, causing the part to get hot and further increasing the resistance.

In any case use a pull-down on the gate. 10k to 100kΩ is fine.

Answer (score 3):

R<sub>DS(on)</sub> is specified at 4.5 V and 10 V, and the performance curves on page 4 of the datasheet show the characteristics at V<sub>GS</sub> > 5 V also, so yes, the gate can handle that voltage, and yes, the transistor can handle 200 mA. That does not necessarily mean it will let 200 mA flow at V<sub>GS</sub> = 4.7 V, though.

Figure 2.4 on page 4 should tell you all you need to know, or at least all you asked, but note that in the DC Electrical Characteristics table on page 1 only 75 mA is *guaranteed* at V<sub>GS</sub> = 4.5 V and V<sub>DS</sub> = 10 V, quite a bit less than figure 2.4 suggests.

Also note that at 200 mA with the stated R<sub>DS(on)</sub> of about 5 Ω the transistor will dissipate about 0.2 W.

You may want to consider a different transistor.